# React Native: Incoming app links not working on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase

In our app, Firebase Dynamic Links stopped working some days ago without changing anything.
This issue occurs on iOS only. We tested old releases of our app, and also old iOS versions, but the links don't work anywhere anymore. So we have no idea what can have changed and caused this issue.

The Xcode Console outputs the following Error when trying to open a dynamic link:

```
-[RNFirebaseLinks application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:]_block_invoke [Line 83] Failed to handle universal link: https://XXX.page.link/XXX
```

The app still opens, but the dispatchUrl callback is not called anymore:

```js
Firebase.links().getInitialLink().then(this.dispatchUrl);
Firebase.links().onLink(this.dispatchUrl);
```

After uninstalling the app and installing it again, the link works one time initially, then stops working again.

We noticed, that `Linking.getInitialURL()` works (only on iOS), but `Linking.addEventListener('url', ...)` does not. So we still can't handle app links that are called while the app is running.

Here are some relevant files from our set-up:

#### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "XXX",
  "version": "3.5.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --scheme Development --configuration Dev.Debug",
    "ios-beta": "react-native run-ios --scheme Beta --configuration Beta.Debug",
    "ios-prod": "react-native run-ios --scheme Production --configuration Production.Debug",
    "ios iPhone 5s": "react-native run-ios --scheme Development --configuration Dev.Debug --simulator \"iPhone 5s\"",
    "ios iPhone 6": "react-native run-ios --scheme Development --configuration Dev.Debug --simulator \"iPhone 6\"",
    "ios iPhone 8": "react-native run-ios --scheme Development --configuration Dev.Debug --simulator \"iPhone 8\"",
    "ios iPhone X": "react-native run-ios --scheme Development --configuration Dev.Debug --simulator \"iPhone X\"",
    "ios iPhone 11": "react-native run-ios --scheme Development --configuration Dev.Debug --simulator \"iPhone 11\"",
    "ios iPad (5th generation)": "react-native run-ios --scheme Development --configuration Dev.Debug --simulator \"iPad (5th generation)\"",
    "android": "react-native run-android --variant=devDebug --appId=XXX",
    "android-dev-release": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDevRelease",
    "android-dev-install": "adb install android/app/build/outputs/apk/dev/release/app-dev-release-unsigned.apk",
    "android-beta": "react-native run-android --variant=betaDebug  --appId=XXX",
    "android-prod": "react-native run-android --variant=prodDebug",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/react-native-maps/enable-google-maps ./ios && rndebugger-open && react-native-schemes-manager all",
    "postversion": "react-native-version --skip-tag --never-amend",
    "git-local-prune": "git branch -vv | grep ': \\(gone\\|entfernt\\)]'|  grep -v '\\*' | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs git branch -d",
    "xcode": "open ios/XXX.xcworkspace"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@turf/distance": "^6.0.1",
    "decko": "1.2.0",
    "firebase": "^5.5.9",
    "geofirestore": "^3.3.1",
    "jsc-android": "224109.x.x",
    "lottie-ios": "^2.5.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^2.5.10",
    "mobx": "^5.15.4",
    "mobx-react": "^5.3.3",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.59.10",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.25.1",
    "react-native-fabric": "0.5.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "~5.2.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.2.1",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-picker": "~0.28.0",
    "react-native-image-progress": "~1.1.1",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "~1.0.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "2.2.24",
    "react-native-maps": "0.23.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-progress": "~3.5.0",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "~3.7.5",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^8.0.11",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.12.1",
    "react-native-youtube": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "0.10.15",
    "rn-placeholder": "~1.3.2",
    "rn-viewpager": "~1.2.9",
    "semver": "~5.6.0",
    "styled-components": "3.4.9",
    "ts-optchain": "~0.1.2",
    "url-parse": "^1.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.5",
    "@types/lodash": "~4.14.120",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.19",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.57.60",
    "@types/react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
    "@types/react-native-i18n": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "~3.7.1",
    "@types/react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^2.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/semver": "~5.5.0",
    "@types/url-parse": "^1.4.2",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "marked": "^0.7.0",
    "metro": "^0.54.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.3",
    "react-native-debugger-open": "~0.3.17",
    "react-native-schemes-manager": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-version": "^2.6.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 140,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "useTabs": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "parser": "typescript"
  },
  "xcodeSchemes": {
    "Debug": [
      "Beta.Debug",
      "Dev.Debug"
    ],
    "Release": [
      "Beta.Release",
      "Dev.Release"
    ],
    "projectDirectory": "ios"
  }
}
```

#### ios/Podfile

```
target 'XXX' do
    rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
    rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

    platform :ios, '9.0'

    # Pods for XXX
    pod 'React', :path => rn_path, :subspecs => [
        'Core',
        'CxxBridge',
        'DevSupport',
        'RCTActionSheet',
        'RCTAnimation',
        'RCTGeolocation',
        'RCTImage',
        'RCTLinkingIOS',
        'RCTNetwork',
        'RCTSettings',
        'RCTText',
        'RCTVibration',
        'RCTWebSocket',
    ]
    pod 'yoga', :path => "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
    pod 'RNI18n', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-i18n'

    pod 'lottie-ios', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-ios'

    pod 'lottie-react-native', :path => '../node_modules/lottie-react-native'

    pod 'react-native-fast-image', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fast-image'

    pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
    pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

    # Required by RNFirebase
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.14.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 5.14.0'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks', '~> 5.14.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.14.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.14.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.14.0'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '~> 5.14.0'

    # Google Tag Manager
    pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 7.0'

    # Crashlytics
    pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.13'
    pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'

    pod 'ReactNativeFabric', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fabric'

    # React Native third party dependencies podspecs
    pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
    #pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
    pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"

    # react-native-maps dependencies
    pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
    pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path  # Unomment this line if you want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
    pod 'GoogleMaps'  # Uncomment this line if you want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
    pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' # Uncomment this line if you want to support GoogleMaps on iOS

    # Youtube dependencies
    pod 'react-native-youtube', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-youtube'
    pod 'XCDYouTubeKit', '~> 2.5'

    pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'
    pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4.0'

    pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/509
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.0.0'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.0.0'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 5.0.0'

    pod 'RNSnackbar', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-snackbar'
    pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'
    pod 'react-native-image-resizer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer'

    pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'

    pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

    target 'XXXTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
            end
        end
        if target.name == "React"
            target.remove_from_project
        end
    end
    system('node ./generatePodsHtml.js')
end
```

#### AppDelegate.m

```swift
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNFirebaseLinks.h"
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <Firebase.h>

#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

#import <RNGoogleSignin/RNGoogleSignin.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Info" ofType: @"plist"];
   NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];
   NSString *apiKey = [dict objectForKey: @"GOOGLE_API_KEY"];
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:apiKey];

  [FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = @"XXX";
  [FIRApp configure];
//  [FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"XXX"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {
  BOOL handled = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application openURL:url options:options];

  if (!handled) {
    handled = [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                                  openURL:url
                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                               annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  }

  if (!handled) {
    handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                             openURL:url
                                                   sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                          annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  }

  if (!handled) {
    handled = [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
  }

  return handled;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
  return [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:response.notification.request.content.userInfo];
  completionHandler();
}

@end
```

Comment: Is it fixed now?